# Returning record of MAX selection with Joined Data

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables, and I'm trying to select the amount of wheat from the newest period where there was production. I need to return the amount, and the name of the Period_ID.

I have a lookup table that easily relates the Period_ID to the correct chronological order. (Table Periods)

```
Table: Periods
Period_ID   |   Period_Order
-----------------------------
18JANP      |   51
18FEBP      |   52     
18MARP      |   53
18APRP      |   54
18MAYP      |   55


Table: Production
Farm_ID     |    Amount      |    Period_ID
--------------------------------------------
11-230      |    1500        |    18JANP
11-230      |    0           |    18FEBP
11-230      |    300         |    18MARP
11-230      |    600         |    18APRP
11-232      |    400         |    18JANP
11-232      |    900         |    18FEBP
11-232      |    300         |    18MARP
11-232      |    0           |    18APRP
11-232      |    100         |    18MAYP
```

This is the query that I'm currently trying:

```
SELECT Farm_ID, 
       MAX(Periods.Period_Order),
       Amount
FROM Production
INNER JOIN Periods ON Production.Period_ID = Periods.Period_ID
WHERE Amount > 0
GROUP BY Farm_ID
```

I know the Amount > 0 piece is really unnecessary in the exact example above, however there may be conditions where the last period returned no amount, so I'd have to be able to look back further.

I expect it to return:

```
Farm_ID: 11-230
Amount: 600
Period_ID: 18APRP
Period_Order: 54
```

AND

```
Farm_ID: 11-232
Amount:100
Period_ID:18MAYP
Period_Order: 55
```

But what I"m getting is the correct Amount and Period_Order, but an incorrect Period_ID:
It's looking like this (just one record for brevity):

```
 Farm_ID: 11-230
 Amount: 600
 Period_ID: 18JANP
 Period_Order: 54
```

It's like the join is working partially, but I don't understand why I'm not getting the correct relational data from the joined table.

Comment: Your qeury is invalid ANSi SQL It does not make sense to mix a non aggregated column what a aggregated function without `GROUP BY`.. But MySQL allows this because it extending GROUP BY.. if MySQL is running sql_mode ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY then your query will fail.

Comment: How ties should be handled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a subquery for get the max period

(orginal question without farm_id)

```
  select a.Period_ID, a.amount, b.Period_Order 
  from Periods a 
  inner join Production b on a.Period_ID = b.Period_ID
  inner join  (
    select  MAX(Periods.Period_Order) max_per
    FROM Periods a 
    INNER JOIN Production b on a.Period_ID = b.Period_ID
    WHERE b.Amount > 0
  ) t on t.max_per = a.order
```

modified question with farm _id

```
  select a.Period_ID, a.amount, b.Period_Order , b.farm_id
  from Periods a 
  inner join Production b on a.Period_ID = b.Period_ID
  inner join  (
    select  MAX(Periods.Period_Order) max_per,  b.farm_id 
    FROM Periods a 
    INNER JOIN Production b on a.Period_ID = b.Period_ID
    WHERE b.Amount > 0
    group by farm_id 
  ) t on t.max_per = a.order and t.farm_id = b.farm_id
```

Comment: OK, so I tried this, and was adding a condition at the end of it, which specified an exact Farm_ID to query out of the database.  My fault, I should have mentioned that  this table would have several different farms in it, and it should be grouped by those to return a complete listing of all the farms and the most recent period they produced.  I edited the original submission to clarify the added field.

Comment: I'm executing this query on 500,000+ records, and it runs the server out of memory.  When I run a min/max on the fields with the conditions and group by, it takes a few seconds. The biggest issue with doing that is that the field that I'm doing the min/max (MAX in this example) is not one that's numerically sortable in such a way that can be done.  Seems there should be an easier way than all the nested joins.